# Sum numbers and group them by the given month, is there a 'best practice'?

Tags: python, sql, django

I don't know what I messed up.

I tried so many methods and solutions and so far this works the best, but the ordering is messy.
I want to sum the expenses grouped by the month extracted from the datefield it was given.

So far I made this:

```
def index(req):
    qs = Expense.objects.filter(pom='OUT').annotate(month=TruncMonth('when')).values('month').annotate(total_amount=Sum('amount')) # pom='OUT' -- expense (there are expenses and incomes)
    return render(req, 'index.html', {'data': qs})
```

which works perfectly, returns them as "sept. 15.000, aug. 10.000" which is nice! But the last/latest month is always at the bottom so I wanted to give it an order_by, which returns each unique object in the model (so if sept. 15.000 came up as sept.15 10.000 and sept.22 5.000, when they're not summed up but returned/shown separately).

What did I mess up?

EQ:
The mentioned query (without order_by) returns a queryset as of
`<QuerySet [{'month': datetime.date(2022, 8, 1), 'total_amount': 15000.0}, {'month': datetime.date(2022, 9, 1), 'total_amount': 16000.0}]>` by default making it look they all have been recorded at the start of the given month.

Drop a reply for further information if I forgot to include something/explained something poorly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Expense.objects.filter(pom='OUT')\
    .values('when__year', 'when__month')\
    .annotate(total_amount=Sum('amount'))\
    .order_by('-when__year','-when__month')
```

I included the year, otherwise it will add total_amount of next years months to this years months. Remove the `-` if you need an ascending order.

This will yield a result like:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'when__year': 2022, 'when__month':9, 'total_amount': 16000.0}, 
    {'when__year': 2022, 'when__month':8, 'total_amount': 15000.0}
]>
```

Edit:

```
Expense.objects.filter(pom='OUT')\
    .values(
        year=models.F('when__year'), 
        month=models.F('when__month')
    ).annotate(total_amount=Sum('amount'))\
    .order_by('-year','-month')
```

This will yield:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'year': 2022, 'month':9, 'total_amount': 16000.0}, 
    {'year': 2022, 'month':8, 'total_amount': 15000.0}
]>
```

Comment: So as I see the first annotation is not required. It works well, thank you! Quick question tho, what difference do the '\' marks do? Also, is it not advised to use TruncMonth or it's just not needed this time and easier to do it this way?

Comment: The \ just allows you to continue the code on a new line. - It's not needed to use query expressions, but is way easier. `Truncdate`, as you saw, will return a `datetime` object, instead of integers, which I (personally) don't find as clean as this. (Way easier for charting the data too!) @ADHDisDEV

Comment: I see. One more question and I'll let you be I swear! I see you use values('when__year'....) to get the year and month from the db, is it possible to rename those terms so the queryset returns "year"/"month" instead of "when__year"?

Comment: Just checked it, it works, but you have to remove the .values() part otherwise it'll leave you with both `when__year` and `year` . Replacing the values to the annotation you just edited in looks actually better, it returns the entire Expense object instead of a custom queryset. Thank you, you are amazing!

Comment: I didn't, just guessing it looks better that way. Altho, I'll stick to your first solution (values one) because the renaming messes with the queryset and duplicates them as I mentioned at the beginning.

Comment: @ADHDisDEV Edited last answer again, this probably works, from looking at the docs. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#values