# Is it possible to return the display name of a choice in Django?

Tags: django, jinja2

So when you make choices for a form/model you do this:

```py
EXP_CHOICES = (
    ('1ST','First'),
    ('2ND','Second'),
.......
    ('XXX','YYY'),
) # where XXX is the value stored in the database and YYY is what you see in a form.
```

This also applies to the queries, so when you have the mentioned choices and select one, do a query on the model and it returns '1ST'/'2ND'/'XXX'.

But what if you want to display the YYY instead? So we know that '1ST' is 'First', but we want to make it user readable.

Is there a way to access that EXP_CHOICES and write out the YYY tied to them, or you must make an if&else/selector to be like

```
{% if data.chosen == '1ST'%}
First
{% elif ... %}
...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use [**`.get_fieldname_display(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display), so if the model field is `chosen`, then it is `get_chosen_display`:

```
{{ data.get_chosen_display }}
```

Comment: Something is not working for me when I do data.get_chosen_display (since the data.chosen returns '1ST', etc) it displays nothing.

Comment: @ADHDisDEV: `data` is a model instance? You did not use `.values(..)` right?

Comment: I had to use ```.values()``` and ```.annotate()``` too in the query, yes. Is that what's messing it up?

Comment: @ADHDisDEV: well then you can not do that. You should *not* use `.values(..)` otherwise you no longer have a model, and thus no longer the logic that "ships" with it. This is one of the (very) many reasons not use use `.values(..)`: django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html

Comment: Sadly I must use values since I didn't find any solutions to another problem which was solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73599667/sum-numbers-and-group-them-by-the-given-month-is-there-a-best-practice/73599848?noredirect=1#comment129969854_73599848

Comment: Should I just rewrite the choices so the displayed text is exactly the same as the text stored in the database? I feel like it's such a small problem yet I spend too much time trying to solve it.